# On hover function, do that, if X has class, do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, which on hover, adds a class to an element.

I would like this to happen only if another div has a specific class.

So Far, I'm trying this without any result:

```
$('.title-overlay').hover(
   function() { 
      $(this).addClass('title-hover'),
   },

   function() {
      if ($('.wmg-container3').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).removeClass('title-hover'),
      }
   }
)
```

As you can see, I'd like the class `title-hover` to be added, but if the `wmg-container3` has the class `open`, this class should be removed .

( all this on hover the class title-overlay)

Thanks for all your help guys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$('.title-overlay').hover(function(){ 

   if($('.wmg-container3').hasClass('open')){
      $(this).removeClass('title-hover')
   }else{
      $(this).addClass('title-hover')
   } 
})
```

Comment: To follow up, on your `handlerOut` callback, you probably want to call `$.removeClass('title-hover')` regardless of the `'.wmg-container3'` element having the open class, since `$.removeClass` will only remove the class if it's present, otherwise do nothing

Comment: @Bwolfing well said

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want following:

- All elements with `title-overlay` class should attach to function hover
- Now when you hover over them it should look for open class first
- If elements with class `wmg-container3` has class `open` then remove title-hover class from it
- apply `title-hover` class to current element

If above logic is correct then code is

```
$('.title-overlay').hover(function(){
      $('.wmg-container3').hasClass('open').removeClass('title-hover');
      $(this).addClass('title-hover');
});
```